# Getting ng model is not a known property of input in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ngmodel

Getting this error below only in 2 components out of 12 components.

```
ng model is not a known property of input
```

Even after importing for Forms module and reactive forms module in `app.modules.ts`. I am getting the err I am using `ngModel` in other components also but they are working fine.

Why I am getting the error only in 2 components?

How to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use your input, not in a form, you can use it with ngModelOptions and make standalone true...

```
[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
```

Comment: I want the inputs in the form

Answer (score 0):

app.module.ts

You have already done this.

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

But just check with you have any other modules rather than `app.module.ts` Then you should imported only in one place.Give a try and see.

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
   FormsModule
],
})
```

Comment: I have only this app.module.ts, even these two components were working don't know how I am getting these errors now.

Answer (score 0):

If these components are registered in another module not in appModule so you need to import FormsModule in that module same as appModule.